Проблема создания автономного приложения jar
Уже несколько часов борюсь с проблемой создания автономного jar файла моего проекта, дошел до того что файл запускается с помощью команды
java --module-path "/home/nazar/openjfx-23.0.1_linux-x64_bin-sdk/javafx-sdk-23.0.1/lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -jar ClickerSupport-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar

Тоесть с указанием всех необходимых модулей, сейчас проблема состоит в том что я хочу создать файл который можно запустить просто командой без указания модулей
java -jar ClickerSupport.jar
Нашел вроде как решение указать в VM Options эту команду
--module-path
"/home/nazar/openjfx-23.0.1_linux-x64_bin-sdk/javafx-sdk-23.0.1/lib:/home/nazar/Стільниця/ClickerSupport/target/classes/nm/"
--add-modules
javafx.controls,javafx.fxml 

Но и тут меня настигла проблема, при запуске проекта ошибка 
Не видит моего модуля, ошибок вроде нигде нет, вот код module-info.java
module nm.cs.clickersupport {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.web;

    requires org.controlsfx.controls;
    requires com.dlsc.formsfx;
    requires net.synedra.validatorfx;
    requires org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx;
    requires org.kordamp.bootstrapfx.core;
    requires eu.hansolo.tilesfx;
    requires com.almasb.fxgl.all;
    requires java.desktop;
    requires jnativehook;
    requires java.logging;

    opens nm.cs.clickersupport to javafx.fxml;
    exports nm.cs.clickersupport;
}

Я уже не знаю что делать, в Project Structure папка lib тоже есть, ниже скину код pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>nm.cs.ClickerSupport</groupId>
    <artifactId>ClickerSupport</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ClickerSupport</name>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>23</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>23</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>5.10.2</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.dlsc.formsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>formsfx-core</artifactId>
            <version>11.6.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.synedra</groupId>
            <artifactId>validatorfx</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.ikonli</groupId>
            <artifactId>ikonli-javafx</artifactId>
            <version>12.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.bootstrapfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrapfx-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>eu.hansolo</groupId>
            <artifactId>tilesfx</artifactId>
            <version>21.0.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.almasb</groupId>
            <artifactId>fxgl</artifactId>
            <version>11.17</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.1stleg</groupId>
            <artifactId>jnativehook</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.13.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>23</source>
                    <target>23</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-package</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>nm.cs.clickersupport.ClickerMainWindow</mainClass>
                            <jlinkImageName>clickersupport</jlinkImageName>
                            <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                            <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                            <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>nm.cs.clickersupport.ClickerMainWindow</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

Прошу помощи так как действительно уже не знаю что делать, если нужна доп. информация пишите.

Собирать проект через maven и не использовать модули. Зависимости на javafx уже есть - это норм. Далее. Создать JavaFxMain (или как-то иначе), который наследуется от Application (JavaFx который) и создать еще Main, который в psvm будет вызывать psvm из JavaFxMain. Я так делал - работало. Собирал в jar вместе с зависимостями и потом паковл в exe.
